# No access to internet on Pop! OS with new ISP and new Modem

Tags: internet, router, pop-os, modem

I'm running Pop! OS 20.04 LTS. Recently switched to new ISP (new modem/router). I have no problem connecting to the modem but then I don't have access to the internet. Some things to note:

- I only have this problem with my linux system. Running dual boot with Windows 7 and I don't seem to have the same problem. No problem with phone or smartTV either
- If I connect to a wifi range extender I also don't have a problem. Even from my linux system.

With my previous ISP I had a similar problem which I would fix by clicking "forget network" and reentering the password. I had to do this every couple of days or so, but it always worked. Now that solution won't work. Any ideas?